# How to make dashboard for json field values in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

If I have json field in my models and I already input some fields

Is this possible to make a dashboard in admin panel just to change the values of the keys in this json and making this keys only readable and can’t be changed?

Also is there any code how to make a table in the admin panel main page? This one is related to make a table that will be shown in the admin panel to change the values of the json field

Thanks in advance!

Making form table that can change the values of this json field in my models based on the keys got returned in the table column as index and the values in the column fields and the row title should be an integar range